# File permissions for letting app as user X authenticate using PAM Radius?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have an application running as user X. User X has primary group Y and a supplementary group Z. I'd like the application authenticate using Radius via PAM. I've installed `libpam-radius-auth` and I know that `/etc/pam_radius_auth.conf` is correctly configured since I can login using SSH (which also uses PAM Radius). My application can also authenticate correctly if I set

```
chmod 444 /etc/pam_radius_auth.conf
```

. Obviously I don't want to do that since the file contains a shared password.

Now, as far as I've understood `/etc/pam_radius_auth.conf` needs to be readable by the process (since PAM invocations runs as the user). What surprises me is that

```
chgrp Z /etc/pam_radius_auth.conf
chmod 440 /etc/pam_radius_auth.conf
```

doesn't work, but

```
chgrp Y /etc/pam_radius_auth.conf
chmod 440 /etc/pam_radius_auth.conf
```

does. *Could anyone explain why the file permission (group Z, that is) doesn't work?* I can read it from `sudo -u X bash`. Could it have something to do with the fact that my (upstart) init file for the application contains:

```
setgid Y
```

? Also, any proposed fix would be great. Since, user Y has the same name as user X (ie. `syslogd:syslogd`) I'd prefer not to have `/etc/pam_radius_auth.conf` owned by group, but rather a global Z group.

**Edit**: Just in case, I've restarted the process after adding the supplemental group Z to the user X. Still doesn't work.

**Edit 2**: Looks like the process is not in the correct group:

```
root@mymachine:/proc/3260# cat status |grep Group
Groups:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty certin I am running into this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/812870